# Babel-watch not loading .jsx files

Tags: node.js, babeljs

[Babel-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-watch) seems to be working fine with .js files.

However, I haven't managed to get it working with .jsx files.
`Cannot find module '../components/Layout'`
^ `import Layout from '../components/Layout';`
(layout is a .jsx file)

Also, it's working just fine with `babel-node`, so I don't think it's an issue with the current source code.

According to their docs:
`-e, --extensions [extensions]  List of extensions to hook into [.es6,.js,.es,.jsx]`

I've tried:

`babel-watch src/server.js --extensions [.js,.jsx]`
`babel-watch src/server.js --extensions [js,jsx]`
`babel-watch src/server.js --extensions .js --extensions .jsx`
`babel-watch src/server.js --extensions js --extensions jsx`
...

But they don't seem to be working. What is the right way of doing so?

Comment: Do you need to put `--extensions` _before_ `src/server.js`? It seems like right now you'd be passing those arguments to your own script, not to `babel-watch`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I've tried this as well, doesn't seem to work. However, I don't think the position matters since I've seen a solved issue on which the user actually writes the parameters at the end.

Comment: Does `babel-watch --extensions .js,.jsx src/server.js` work?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Nope, it gives the exact same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with babel-watch itself.

This problem has been reported here https://github.com/kmagiera/babel-watch/issues/21 and fixed in 2.0.3 (https://github.com/kmagiera/babel-watch/releases/tag/v2.0.3-rc0)

Just update the version of babel-watch and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

```
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
```

When you use an import statement without the extension it defaults to a `.js` so it would become `Layout.js` but you are targeting a `.jsx` file so use:

```
import Layout from '../components/Layout.jsx';
```

Comment: Did you try adding .jsx to the end?

Comment: It does work. But modifying the source code shouldn't be the way to proceed. If I don't get this to work on its own, I'd rather use another tool such as `nodemon`.